# get product precision in openerp report parser

Tags: python, odoo, rml

I want to get a product precision in a `report parser` to use it in `RML` code to replace `get_digits` methode.

I have this code:

```
class my_report(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(my_report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'precision': self.get_precision,
        })
    def get_precision(self, product):
        ...
        return precision
```

Is it possible?

Comment: have you tried with given answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

For example, I have below line in my .rml file. We can direct assign any static value like

```
[[ formatLang(line.price_unit, digits=4) ]]
```

Comment: I want some thing like : `digits=_function()`